# Angular 2 - How to receive a variable inside a ngFor scope

Tags: angular

I have a simple component like this:

```
export class MysidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    activen: number
    {...}
}
```

and I want in inside an ngFor when the index equals with active, a class to be added.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" [class.active]="i==activen">{{ item }}</a>
```

Can you help me?
Thank in advance

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't contain a problem.